# Add a variable to column footer iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to add a variable to column footer of my table. It is the sum of the column values. eg: total sales, if column name is sales.

But when i try it it says variable not found for some reason.
I have positioned the table in title band because if i put it in detail band the table repeats multiplied by the number of rows in the table.
5rows = 5pages with the same table.

Can someone please help me since im new to jasper and ireport.

I am using ireport 5.0.0

Thank you

Comment: Where did you define the variable? In the subdataset for the table?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this on your xml

```
<field name="total_column" class="java.lang.Long"/>
```

and have this as your text field expression

```
$F{total_column}
```

Change the name to whatever you are using.

Answer (score 1):

We always define variables at the center level so make sure if you are using any sub data-set for your table component, copy the same query in main report query area, then add a variable
and change these properties in Ireport :-

```
Variable class :- java.lang.integer or java.math.BigDecimal
Calculation :-     Sum
Variable expression:-  $F{total_sales}
```

XML:- if you are not using Ireport

```
  <variable name="total_sales" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{total_sales}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

and after this you can use this variable for sum.

Comment: I dont use any sub data set. I use the main data set for the table as well.

Comment: anyway did you try to check variable properties ?